# Yosemite: Three Finger / Look Up Trackpad Gesture Not Working

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad, osx-yosemite, gestures

The Look Up / Three Finger trackpad gesture is not working in Yosemite for my user. This gesture was working in Mavericks, but stopped when I upgraded.
If I log in with the Guest user, the Look Up gesture does work.

What I've attempted:

- Enabling/Disabling all of the Trackpad gestures in the Trackpad preference pane
- Deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that I'm using ScrollReverser

https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/

> The three finger tap gesture that does a dictionary lookup no longer
>   functions when Scroll Reverser is active. Yep, sorry. It's a known bug
>   without a known fix.

Closing ScrollReverser allows me to do the lookup gesture